# how to change the value of a static variable from a static method of another class

Tags: java, static

hi guys i got this variable in my first class

```
public static double credit;
```

in the constructor of the first class i got

```
credit=0.0;
```

then i got this listener-code that shows me the value on the graphic window after the user adds the funds

```
Catalogo.addCredit(credit);
creditLabel.setText("Credito: " + getCredit()+"€");
```

using those 2 static methods, this for the value return ( in the first class)

```
public static double getCredit() {
      return credit; }
```

and for increase the funds i use this one of another class

```
public static void addCredit(double creditl) {

  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
  String cred = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Inserisci l'importo da aggiungere:");

  if (cred == null) {
      return; }

  if ((cred.matches("[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+")) || (cred.matches("[0-9]+"))) { //checks if the string is a valid double value or an int value
      double credits = (double) Double.parseDouble(cred); //conversion into double
      if (credits >= 0.0) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Credito aggiornato con successo");
          creditl = creditl + credits;} }

  if (!(cred.matches("[0-9]+")) && !(cred.matches("[0-9]*\\.[0-9]+"))) { //checks if the user didn't insert a correct double or int
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Importo inserito errato");
      addCredit(creditl); }
}
```

now the problem is that the credit variable doesn't increase at all and i don't know why it seems that all is good, or maybe am i missing something ? the input goes wel in the mean that it checks for the proper value and then it says that the credit has been updated but it's not and i don't know why this is happening

NOTE: i have tried to make this variable a non static var and renaming all methods to non static but it seems that it's the same thing, same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not setting the `credit` class variable anywhere in your code. You have another local variable named `creditl`, maybe this is a typo that is part of your problem.

Specifically, this line might be the issue:

```
   creditl = creditl + credits;
```

(In any case, you should revisit your design.)

Comment: no it's not a typo i used to call my local variables adding an "l" for specify the local meaning, which is a bit tricky i know but just to say that's not a typo

Comment: Ok. Still, you are not actually setting the `credit` variable anywhere in your code.

Comment: But you are not updating it after that.

Comment: i am sry mate i don't get what you are meaning, because the variable should update with the addCredit method and i don't know why it doesn't and then the set text on the label should let me visualize it right after the addCredit call

Comment: Here "creditl = creditl + credits" you work only with your variables inside the method. But you must work on your static "credit" from the other class.

Comment: oh i got it now and how to pass the "pointer" instead of the value ? casue i don't know how to do it on primitive types

Comment: There are no pointers. `double` is always passed by value. At some point in your `addCredit` method, you need to assign the new value to the `credit` variable.

Comment: ok thx a lot for the help i achieved that by managing to return a double value from the method and then assigning to the real variable